# Loading large files for application, functions, classes

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system, large-files

I'm wondering what the experts have to say about loading large files containing functions or classes versus calling them as required.

I'm using Codeigniter, but I'm thinking the question is framework neutral. I'm also thinking that CMSs like Wordpress appear to load a ton of utility functions for every page load.

Until now I've loaded code as required, but I'm wondering if there's really a huge performance hit if I combine many files and load them so they are "just there" ready to use.

If I have 20 core function files/classes that I use that each have say 200 lines but instead combine them all and load 4k lines on each page load, am I getting convenience over speed, or doesn't it matter -- within reason?

How do others deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about i/o speed or memory consumption until you need to. You won't notice the difference.

Also, keep your code as modular as possible so that it can be re-used in other contexts.